# getaddrinfo() seems to block when using eventlet

Tags: python, django, celery, blocking, eventlet

I run my Django-celery tasks using eventlet. But something is still blocking. I used eventlet's blocking detection and found out that getaddrinfo() is blocking. I read somewhere that I have to install the "dnspython" package, but it makes no difference with or without. It is installed at the moment:

```
dnspython                 - A DNS toolkit for Python
  INSTALLED: 1.11.0 (latest)
```

It is also funny that the blocking appears somewhere inside eventlet's code (eventlet.green.socket).

I run celery like that:

```
/var/www/myproject/async_manage.py celeryd -B \
     --schedule=/var/www/myproject/celerybeat-schedule \
     --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet -c 1000 \
     --settings=myproject.settings.myproject_deployment
```

My custom async_manage.py (parts of it):

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

import eventlet
import eventlet.debug

os.environ["EVENTLET_NOPATCH"] = 'True'
eventlet.monkey_patch()
eventlet.debug.hub_prevent_multiple_readers(False)
eventlet.debug.hub_blocking_detection(True, 0.1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Task myproject.apps.myapp.tasks.mytask with id f8794028-699e-43ba-b48f-3d81b7614f1f raised exception:
'RuntimeError("Blocking detector ALARMED atTraceback(filename=\'/var/www/virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py\', lineno=43, function=\'create_connection\', code_context=[\'    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):\\\\n\'], index=0)",)'
```

Do you have any clue how to fix that? This makes no sense to me.

Thanks in advance,
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

You can start with removing `os.environ["EVENTLET_NOPATCH"] = 'True'`
Because it is misleading. It does not do anything. Eventlet never supported this environment variable.

Then, try to execute this code:

```
from eventlet.green import socket
print(socket.getaddrinfo.__module__)
```

Comment: Why is that? Do you have any further explanation? I actually copied it from here: https://gist.github.com/joshbohde/821848